# Why my applyBindings doesn't work? Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hello I am trying simply to create input and iframe and when I paste the YouTube link the iframe should change with the new src. I have done this so far

```
<div class="heading">id <input data-bind="text: youtubeLink"/></div>
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="444" height="250" frameborder="0" data-bind="attr: { src: linkEmbed }"></iframe>
```

And in the script:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.youtubeLink = ko.observable('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UNkmlCKw9M');
    this.linkEmbed = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
                var extract = this.youtubeLink().replace("/watch?v=", "/embed/");
                console.log(extract)
                return extract;
        },
        write: function (value) {
                 this.youtubeLink();
        },
        owner: this
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel());
```

This works exactly as I want but the video wont change if I paste another link in the input.

I am using this from knockout documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html

Comment: It looks like your write function isn't assigning the value to the 'youtubeLink' property.

Comment: The problem isn't with applyBindings or your computed observable. The problem is with your src binding of an iframe. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523457/how-to-data-bind-content-for-an-iframe-using-knockoutjs

Comment: If you tell me exactly what is wrong with my iframe src i will be greatfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You don't call `new` on your model, but you wrote it as a constructor
2. You use `text` binding instead of `value` binding for your input
3. Your computed's write doesn't assign, but you don't need it anyway

Once you correct those, it works.

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var model = {};
    model.youtubeLink = ko.observable('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UNkmlCKw9M');
    model.linkEmbed = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var result = model.youtubeLink().replace("/watch?v=", "/embed/")
        return result;
    });
    return model;
}
ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ueoob7ne/2/

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** jQuery hides knockout bind errors.

Another thing that breaks it....

jQuery is known to catch exceptions and hide them.  I had to step through knockout-debug.js AND THEN jquery.js until i got to a part that looks like this (around line 3600)

```
// Only normal processors (resolve) catch and reject exceptions
    process = special ?
        mightThrow :
            function() {
            try {
                mightThrow();
            } catch ( e ) {
```

wouldn't you know it... I put a watch on (e) an here was what I found hidden in there:

```
Error: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return ko.toJSON(vm.model(),null,2) }"
Message: Multiple bindings (if and text) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element
```